# Problem with unbounded implicit region over integers

Tags: regions

I have a region specified implicitly, and want to find the region bounds, however there are some problems when the region is defined over the integers and it is an unbounded region. This unbounded region over the reals works fine:

```
RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[2 <= b <= Infinity, {b}], "Minimal"]
```

> `{{2, \[Infinity]}}`

This however, returns unevaluated:

```
RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[Element[b, Integers] && 2 <= b <= Infinity, {b}], "Minimal"]
```

The problem is that `BoundedRegionQ` does not work correctly here (I suspect a bug):

```
BoundedRegionQ@ImplicitRegion[Element[b, Integers] && 2 <= b <= Infinity, {b}]
```

> ```
> During evaluation of In[806]:= BoundedRegionQ::nmet: Unable to determine whether
>   the region ImplicitRegion[b\[Element]Integers&&2<=b<=\[Infinity],{b}]
>   is bounded. >>
> ```

Does anyone have any idea how I could overcome this issue to find the appropriate region bounds? Note, that regions can be nonconstant (containing symbolic parameters, for which `ConstantBoundaryQ` might return `False`). An example:

```
Refine[RegionBounds[
  ImplicitRegion[Element[(a|n), Integers] && 4 <= b <= n, {b}], 
  "Minimal"], n > 4]
```

where I expect the answer to be `{{4, n}}`, however the `RegionBounds` expression remains unevaluated. The correct answer is returned only if I omit the `Element[(a|n), Integers]` specification.

(version 10.4)